# Froala toolbar popups appear at the bottom even though there is no space left

Tags: reactjs, froala

I am using froala editor in my react code. The toolbar will be placed at the bottom of the window. So when a user clicks on the link or table button the popup is opening below the toolbar even though there is no space. Here is my code

```
<FroalaEditor
                config={
                  {
                    toolbarContainer: '#toolbar',
                    attribution: false,
                    toolbarButtons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'insertLink', 'insertTable', 'colorText', 'link'],
                    colorsBackground: [
                      '#15E67F', '#E3DE8C', '#D8A076', '#D83762', '#76B6D8', 'REMOVE',
                      '#1C7A90', '#249CB8', '#4ABED9', '#FBD75B', '#FBE571', '#FFFFFF'
                    ],
                    colorsDefaultTab: 'background',
                    imageEditButtons: ['imageDisplay', 'imageAlign', 'imageStyle', 'imageSize', 'imageInfo', '|', 'imageCaption', 'imageLink', 'imageRemove'],
                    colorsStep: 6,
                    colorsText: [
                      '#15E67F', '#E3DE8C', '#D8A076', '#D83762', '#76B6D8', 'REMOVE',
                      '#1C7A90', '#249CB8', '#4ABED9', '#FBD75B', '#FBE571', '#FFFFFF'
                    ],
                    linkInsertButtons: ['linkBack'],
                    linkEditButtons: ['linkOpen', 'linkEdit', 'linkRemove'],
                    useClasses: false,
                    imageMaxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024,
                    imageUpload: true,
                    events: {
                      initialized() {
                        const editor = this;
                        tribute.attach(editor.el);
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
                model={editorState}
                onModelChange={this.handleEditorChange}
              />
```

[image]

Is there any way I can make the popup to open above the toolbar ?

Any help would be really thankfull

Comment: Try and use something like as it would save much of the hard work that has to be done to move that up. Its already up in this link : https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/predefined-height/    and even here : https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/toolbar-bottom/

Comment: passing toolbarBotton:true worked. Thanka a lot